# Access HTML page in C#

Tags: c#, html, controls

Basically I have two files:
`details.html`
`details.cs`

I would like to use `details.cs` to write values to `details.html` but the html textbox still stays the same.

**details.html**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="details.cs" 
Inherits="Details.DetailsHTML" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="txt_details" type="text" name="txt_details" runat="server"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**details.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace Details
{
    public partial class DetailsHTML : Page
    {
        //Declare controls used
        protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText txt_details;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strValue = Page.Request.Form ["txt_details"].ToString();
            strValue = "test";
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can not access control in .html from .cs** file. You are trying to use `aspx` page as you are inherting from `Page` class but naming .html, you are problably not using visual studio. Use details.aspx and details.aspx.cs. If you do not have Visual Studio then you can download free express version from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads). This [link](http://webproject.scottgu.com/csharp/helloworld/helloworld.aspx) explains how to create web application project using visual studio. The [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbhbb82%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Creating a Basic Web Page with Code Separation in Visual Studio will help you in creating the web page and access html control on server side.

```
txt_details.Value = "your value";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt_details.Value = "test";
```

This should help

Answer (score 0):

> You can acess by a name of control eg:

```
txt_details.Value = "Test"
```